# "AttributeError: 'SelectorList' object has no attribute 'get'" in Scrapy Cloud

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm setting a scraper with Scrapy that works well on my laptop. But this message appers when I try this same spider on scrapy cloud:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/tmp/unpacked-eggs/__main__.egg/ccv_spiders/spiders/gmitem.py", line 31, in parse
    data["marque"] = caritem.css("div.make::text").get().strip().split(" ", 2)[1]
AttributeError: 'SelectorList' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Here is my code:

```
def start_requests(self):
        for item in self.data:
            request = scrapy.Request(item['gm_url'], callback=self.parse)
            request.meta['item'] = item
            yield request

    def parse(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        item['results'] = []

        for caritem in response.css("div.car-item-border"):
            data = AuctionItem()
            urllot = "https://www.website.com/img/auctions/byLot/"
            urlbase = "https://www.website.com/img/auctions/car/thumb/"
            data["marque"] = caritem.css("div.make::text").get().strip().split(" ", 2)[1]
            data["model"] = caritem.css("div.make::text").get().strip().split(" ", 2)[2]
            data["model_year"] = caritem.css("div.make::text").get().strip().split(" ", 1)[0]
            data["price_str"] = caritem.css("div.price::text").get().strip().replace(",", " ")
            if caritem.css("div.price::text").get().find("Estimate"):
                data["sold"] = True
            else:
                data["sold"] = False
            data["auction_house"] = caritem.css("div.auctionHouse::text").get().split("-", 1)[0].strip()
            data["auction_country"] = caritem.css("div.auctionHouse::text").get().rsplit(",", 1)[1].strip()
            data["auction_date"] = caritem.css("div.date::text").get().replace(",", "").strip()
            if caritem.css("div.view-auction a::attr(href)").get().find("/auction-cars/show-backup-image"):
                data["auction_url"] = caritem.css("div.view-auction a::attr(href)").get()
            else:
                data["auction_url"] = None
            data["image_urls"] = caritem.css("img.img-responsive::attr(src)").get()
            if urllot in data["image_urls"]:
                data["image_cloud"] = caritem.css("img.img-responsive::attr(src)").get().replace(urllot,"https://res.cloudinary.com/ccv/image/upload/auctions/")
                data["image_cloud"] = re.sub(r"(?<=[A-Z])/*(?=\d)", "-", data["image_cloud"])
            elif urlbase in data["image_urls"]:
                data["image_cloud"] = caritem.css("img.img-responsive::attr(src)").get().replace(urlbase, "https://res.cloudinary.com/ccv/image/upload/auctions/")
            item['results'].append(data)

        yield item
```

Is there any problem with my Python version ? It works with Anaconda and Python 3 on my laptop and I don't understand why it seems to be using python 2.7 via "/usr/local/lib/python2.7..."

Besides, my JSON output doesn't show any of the results's arrays.

Comment: try `extract_first()` instead of `get()`

Comment: That's it ! Thank you very much !

Comment: @Umair, may I ask you to write small explanation? It is very interesting, I thought they are equal.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is all about libraries' version.

Both `get` and `getall` methods were first introduced by [Parsel](https://parsel.readthedocs.io) (Scrapy's parse library) at version [1.2.0](https://parsel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/history.html#id6), which is not granted if you're using Scrapy 1.5.2 or lower.

You can use `extract_first` and `extract` as replacements, or upgrade Scrapy to [1.6+](https://scrapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/news.html#scrapy-1-6-0-2019-01-30).

Comment: Spot on dude! :)

Comment: https://github.com/scrapy/parsel/blob/v1.5.2/parsel/selector.py#L132